# Getting Yesterday's date with specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which shows the CPU usage by hour. However what I want is show CPU usage for yesterday between 08:00 to 19:00.

I am really far away from t-SQL and I need your help.

```
DECLARE @ts BIGINT;
SELECT @ts =(SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info);

SELECT 
         DATEADD(ms,-60 *(@ts - [timestamp]),GETDATE()) AS [EventDate] ,
        100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS [Total(%)], 
        SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQL Server(%)]
FROM (SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]','int')AS record_id, 
record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]','int')AS [SystemIdle], 
record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]','int')AS [SQLProcessUtilization], 
[timestamp]      
FROM (SELECT[timestamp], convert(xml, record) AS [record]             
FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers             
WHERE ring_buffer_type =N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'AND record LIKE'%%')AS x )AS y 
where [EventDate]  > dateadd(day,-1, getdate())  -- Throws an error like 'EventDate Invalid Column'
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

Comment: **-- Throws an error like 'EventDate Invalid Column'** - change `EventDate` to `DATEADD(ms,-60 *(@ts - [timestamp]),GETDATE())`

Comment: @yes it worked but how can i specify hour. could you please write as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is pretty long and complicated so I've not tailored this to the above, but this might help you get the answer you're after. Just run the below:

```
DECLARE @startTime AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @endTime AS DATETIME;    

SET @startTime = DATEADD(
                     HOUR ,
                     8 ,
                     CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME));
SET @endTime = DATEADD(
                     HOUR ,
                     19 ,
                     CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME));

-- check the values    
SELECT @startTime AS startTime ,
       @endTime AS endTime;

-- filter your query - edit the below with your table(s)
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable AS
WHERE yourDate >= @startTime AND yourDate <= @endTime
```

Note: just comment out the final `SELECT` to see the values it generates.